# Why responsive stops

Tags: css

I'm trying to build out this hero image and it need to be responsive. I haven't added my @media CSS yet, but by default, shouldn't this image I have in here scale with the page? It stops around 1107px width.

```css
.wrapper-home{ 
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#hero-image-home{
  background-image:url(http://www.destinationworcester.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/halloween-central-mass-blog.jpg);
  position:relative;
  height:640px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.header-home {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);  

}

.header-home h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-home h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-home">
  <div id="hero-image-home">
    <div class="header-home">
      <h1>asg sfgasfjkhjhsdg  sdjagk jfjasdgh f</h1>
      <h2>asjkldfh sdjklfh lasdjkfh ajklsdfh lkajsdf</h2>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
 
</div>
```

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't duplicate the issue. I'm able to see the background go past 1880. Are you just trying to get ride of the padding around the background?

Comment: I updated the code. I'm trying to have the BG image scale dynamically with he page using just CSS and the @media. Making sure the text stays in the middle of that DIV.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the original code?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to get that image that 1200px by 640px scale dynamically as the page goes in responsive. It should start out at full height and width centered, then get smaller (still staying centered) while the page gets smaller. But right now the DIVS act how they are supposed to but the image after a certain point stops re-sizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-size: 100%;
```

May help you to scale background image.

```css
.wrapper-home{ 
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

#hero-image-home{
  background-image:url(http://www.destinationworcester.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/halloween-central-mass-blog.jpg);
  position:relative;
  height: 640px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.header-home {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
    transform: translate(0,-50%);  

}

.header-home h1 {
 font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.header-home h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-home">
  <div id="hero-image-home">
    <div class="header-home">
      <h1>asg sfgasfjkhjhsdg  sdjagk jfjasdgh f</h1>
      <h2>asjkldfh sdjklfh lasdjkfh ajklsdfh lkajsdf</h2>
     
    </div>
  </div>
  
 
</div>
```

Comment: Beautiful! This worked. Thanks for the help everyone!